# My Node.JS login is not working Despite Trying to Solve Using Several Tutorials

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to create a simple node.js CRUD application just to put into practice what I have learnt, however, I have been stuck on this this issue for about two days now.

I am using passport to authenticate users, however, when valid passwords are entered it is not redirecting and justs remain on the login page.  Here is my code:

```
//**Model**
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

//Passport Config File
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const User = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'username'},(username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({username: username })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "User Not Found" });
          }
          //match password
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false, { message: "Password is Incorrect" });
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    })
  );

//**Route**
router.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    })(req, res, next)
})

//**DB**

username: "bobby"
password: "password"
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes and it did not reveal anything